# .Net idioms learned through experience?

Tags: c#, .net, idioms

I'm new to .Net world, my primary language was C++ where there are lot of idioms that help code better(RAII,PIMPL...). What are the common idioms available for c#.

Comment: If you're coming from C++ this article might be worth looking at: http://bit.ly/chVM2k

Comment: This site has a bunch of good ones.  http://blueonionsoftware.com/blog.aspx?p=f0fc19c1-bb4f-4985-adcf-a9fec3a754a1

Comment: There are a lot of idioms needed when writing C#/Java code,as there are a lot of traps in C#/Java than C++

Answer (score 3):

I don't give any idioms, but since you move from C++ it maybe interesting:

[MSDN: C# for C++ Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

> The following table contains important comparisons between C# and native C++, which does not use /clr. If you are a C++ programmer, this table will give you the most important differences between the two languages at a glance.

[C++ -> C#: What You Need to Know to Move from C++ to C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301520.aspx)

> C# builds on the syntax and semantics of C++, allowing C programmers to take advantage of .NET and the common language runtime. While the transition from C++ to C# should be a smooth one, there are a few things to watch out for including changes to new, structs, constructors, and destructors. This article explores the language features that are new to C# such as garbage collection, properties, foreach loops, and interfaces. Following a discussion of interfaces, there's a discussion of properties, arrays, and the base class libraries. The article concludes with an exploration of asynchronous I/O, attributes and reflection, type discovery, and dynamic invocation.

[Sharp New Language: C# Offers the Power of C++ and Simplicity of Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb984953.aspx)

> Many developers wish there was a language that was easy to write, read, and maintain like Visual Basic, but that still provided the power and flexibility of C++. For those developers, the new C# language is here. Microsoft has built C# with type-safety, garbage collection, simplified type declarations, versioning and scalability support, and lots of other features that make developing solutions faster and easier, especially for COM+ and Web Services. This article gives you a first look at C#, a language you are going to be hearing lots more about in the very near future.

[C++ vs. C# - a Checklist from a C++ Programmers Point of View](http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2007/03/06/c-vs-c-a-checklist-from-a-c-programmers-point-of-view/)

> And so, without any further ado and very brief, here is my list of differences between the two, sorted into three categories: things I like better in C#, things I like better in C++ and things where I could not make up my mind.

[10 Things C++ Developers Learning C# Should Know](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/08/12/10-things-c-developers-learning-c-should-know.aspx)

> This article does not describe all the differences and even skips some obvious ones (single vs. multiple inheritance for example), nor are these necessarily the most important, it's just a set of 10 I've been thinking about, and more articles may follow if people find these useful.